# Protocol error in TDS stream - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to know why we get this error when a procedure is called as a step inside job

> Protocol error in TDS stream [SQLSTATE HY000] (Error 0)  String data, right truncation [SQLSTATE 01004] (Message 0)

It's not string truncation because we debugged the procedure in the same environment and it works as expected, when we re run the job it runs fine

Any ideas or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Happens sometimes but not in all the run

Comment: "It's not string truncation" It **is** string truncation but in a way you do not expect.

Comment: No its not string truncation, because the error didn't replicate for the same process in the same environment after we re run the job. It's something related to protocol error

Comment: Well, if it is the same environment you should see exactly the same behavior. Something is different.; Error 0 is "success". It doesn't look like there really is a protocol error. The message is probably misleading. Execute a query that deliberately leads to string truncation. You'll probably see that the same error comes up.